# How to transfer the value of the same combo box to another combo box but the value can not be equal or less than the index number

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

So there are two combo box with equal values, But when you have to select the value in the first combo box , the second combo box should not display the same or equal value as the first one. Please any suggestions will helpful.

Comment: What have you tried?  And can you give examples of what outcome should be like?

Comment: tried a lot of stuff but don't know how to implement the criteria about the drop down list, do you have any sugestions

Comment: well don not have doc well value . the value it self is from asp . do not know what to do.

Comment: out come should be like if have four categories and  select the zero index so it should display all the results. if  next one is selected it will display three on second one and if two so on on. like that

Comment: 1 , 2, 3 ,4                               1, 2 ,3 ,4                        if 1 > 1, 2,3 ,4                                                                if 2>2, 3,4                                                                        if 3> 3,4

Comment: @tom can you take a look

Comment: populate first combo.  On selection, populate second combo, but evaluate against what was chosen in the first box and don't populate if it meets your criteria.

Comment: @APrough do you have a code for this or smthing

Comment: No, all you have to do is just use the ItemSelected event of the first comboBox to trigger the populate of your second.  It's relatively easy.